# List Certain Columns in Pandas

Tags: python

I have this List

[image]

And I want t list The name and short name of every airfield & display the results

I have tried

```
df1 = df['Name':'ShortName']
df1 = df.ix[:, 'Name':'ShortName']

newdf = df[df.columns[9:12]]
```

I have also tried other commands, and none seem to work. Any ideas would help thanks.

Comment: I get this error: `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: If you want all the columns between `Name` and `ShortName` then use `.loc`: `df.loc[:, 'Name':'ShortName']`

Comment: No, I just want the Name and ShortName columns.

Comment: Then use a `,` (comma) with a nested index: `df[['Name', 'ShortName']]`. `:` (colon) is used for slicing.

Comment: Using `df[['Name', 'ShortName']]` gives me `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: Can't reproduce your error.